# Django: template inheritance override on include

Tags: django, django-templates

For example I have `top.html` which will be included from within `base.html`. 
How to override contents of `top.html` after including?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't understand templates idealogy.
Right way is create base.html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Some app - {% block header %}{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{% block title %}Default title{% endblock %}</h1>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

And then in page.html you can override header for example:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Some page{% endblock %}
{% block header %}Overriden header{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    Some content
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I figured it out, thanks @Stanislav Feldman though the examples do not satisfy my requirements)